# Why does Stack Exchange not allow signing in with a username?

Tags: feature-request, login, display-names

When I look at the URL to my profile I see https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/344066/jack-siro. I want to believe that `344066` is my userid or member number and `jack-siro` is my username all automatically generated by the system. So why not have me sign in with my username like we do on all other sites like Facebook, Twitter, and so forth.

I would like to be using my username to login to SO. The system can make us have unique usernames to use to login with.

Comment: It is not your username but your displayname. Those are not unique on SE.

Comment: Suppose this is implemented, what do you suggest the current [nine-thousand or so](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1021565) Alex's should do?

Comment: User names on sites like Facebook, Twitter, etc are **unique**, equivalent of the numeric user ID we have on Stack Exchange. Even Facebook and Twitter won't let us sign in with the chosen **display name**, which you refer to here as "username".

Answer (score 3):

Usernames/displayed names are not unique. There are at least 3 users with the username "Gandalf" - it would not be trivial to determine which account to log into.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an auto-generated username. It is your "display name" which can be edited under the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab. Since it is not unique, it cannot be used for signing in due to the apparent ambiguity.